# What is wrong in this regular expression and how can I improve it?

Tags: php, regex

I'm using the following regex code:

```
^[a-z0-9_-]{3,15}$^
```

I'm using this for username validation and I want it to match alphanumeric characters, `-` , `_` and periods.

The following weird thing happens:

It doesn't match this:

```
bla.b
```

But it matches this one:

```
bla.blabla
```

How can I change this, so that it matches both? I still would like to be able to change the min and max characters freely. (btw. there maybe more wrong things about this regex. This one I discovered accidentally)

**UPDATE:** I should mention that I'm using this in CakePHP validation and this gives me an error:

```
^[a-z0-9_.-]{3,15}$
```

this is the error:

```
Warning (2): preg_match() [function.preg-match]: No ending delimiter '^' found
```

Comment: How exactly your regex matches a `dot (.)`?

Comment: @RohitJain I don't know. I'm using this in CakePHP and it matches :/

Comment: Accidently discovered regexes often come with more than one regex. Learn them, it's often better to write your own, because you then learn more.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You made a little mistake and forgot to put the `^` at the beginning. Choosing a different delimiter might make that more visible:

```
^[a-z0-9_-]{3,15}$^    // your non-working version
^                 ^

/^[a-z0-9_-]{3,15}$/  // using / as delimiters instead, setting the beginning
 ^
```

Remember:

- `^`  - marks the beginning of the subject
- `$`  - marks the end of the subject

Both are part of the pattern. The delimiters are used to separate the pattern from the modifiers (you don't use any modifiers here).

Alternatively you can denote the beginning and end as well with `\A` and `\Z` if it helps.

To now also match the dot, add it to your character class:

```
/^[a-z0-9_.-]{3,15}$/
          ^
```

Comment: Oh man, it never occurred to me that OP was using it as a delimiter, looked like a typo. +1

Comment: Well, add the `/` delimiter around if you don't want to see that error.

Comment: I already did and it's working. I will accept your answer in a minute.

Answer (score 5):

```
^[a-z0-9_-]{3,15}$^
```

should be:

```
^[a-z0-9_-]{3,15}$
```

`^` denotes the start of the string, and `$` denotes the end of string.

Comment: hakre's answer worked for me, but see my question again please. Do you know why?

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
/^[a-z0-9_\.\-]{3,15}$/
```

If you want to match a username then you probably do not want it to start or end with a dot. In that case you can use this:

```
/^(?<!\.)[a-z0-9_\.\-]{3,15}(?!\.)$/
```

This is how that regex breaks down:

1. `^` means the "beginning of the string"
2. `(?<!\.)` makes sure that the username cannot start with a dot
3. `[a-z0-9\._-]{3,15}` means 3 to 15 alphanumeric characters, dots, underscores and hyphens
4. `(?!\.)` makes sure that the username cannot end with a dot
5. `$` means the "end of the string"

If you allow uppercase characters then you can shorten the regex slightly:

```
/^(?<!\.)[\w\.\-]{3,15}(?!\.)$/
```

The `\w` is short for `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, also called *word characters*.

Another way of making sure that a username does not start or end with a dot is to use three consecutive `[]`, like so:

```
/^[\w\-][\w\.\-]{1,13}[\w\-]$/
```

It can be useful if you need to match something in Javascript which, I believe, does not support lookbehind and lookahead.

Comment: Very complete and nice answer, even more than I wanted. Hakre was first otherwise I would have accepted this.